# Error clearing the cache

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

Whenever I clear the cache (app/console cache:clear) I get this error:

[InvalidArgumentException]
The file "C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\cache\de_/config/config_dev.yml" does not exist.

My app is Symfony 2.3.

Comment: What are you doing to clear the cache? Please post some code so we can see what you're doing wrong. At the least, if you copy that file path, does it exist when you open your file explorer?

Comment: Can you provide your full deps composer list ? You can do it by typing `composer info -i`

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the proper environment along with your cache:clear command. Which is

php app/console cache:clear --env=prod or php app/console cache:clear --env=dev

Is this project working under a SVN? If so, try performing a SVN Cleanup before removing the cache. By the way, you can go to app/cache folder and manually delete the cache in relevant environment.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I am agree, I am doing php - symfony coding in ubuntu, sometime @ home,I  use windows7 , many time cache:clear command does not wotk, I used to delete cache and logs folders from app folder. then it works smoothly... sometime wonder why so strong cache management in window only.......

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is wrong in the path `C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\cache\de_/config/config_dev.yml`. Maybe "de_" should have been "dev". Follow path `C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\cache\` and find out if the suitable folder is there.

Another thing you can do but not recommended is to simply delete the cache folder `C:\wamp\www\sylius\app\cache\` (if you want to clear all the cache) or just one inside (dev, prod) corresponding to the environment you want the cache to be cleared.